# Passing an argument to the 'new' action of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have 2 models:

```
FoodOrder
Sales
SalesMeeting
```

Salesmen often order food when they are having a meeting, so we'd like to associate a particular FoodOrder with a SalesMeeting.

I can so this by calling:

```
new_food_order_path(@sales_meeting)
```

and through

```
params[:format]
```

get the id of the object I want to link it to.

However, let's say coders get jealous and they want to order food to when they are at a Hackathon.

This would be fine if I could pass in:

```
 new_food_order_path(@hackathon, "Hackathon")
```

AND

```
 new_food_order_path(@sales_meeting, "SalesMeeting")
```

But Action Controller gets angry at me when I try to so telling me that there is an

```
undefinded method gsub for Nil::NilClass
```

Is there a way to do this?

Edit: Actually, I could just pass in a hash...which I figured out while writing the question...I wonder if that is what Rails does...

Maybe there is a way to do this with redirects as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass in a Hash!

```
<%= link_to "New Food Order", new_food_order_path({ id: @sales_meeting, model: "SalesMeeting" }) %>

<%= link_to "New Hackathon", new_food_order_path({ id: @hackathon, model: "Hackathon" }) %>
```